# Pi zero w BLE connection disconnects

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, connection

I have some strange problem with connection between raspberry pi zero w and BLE device (electric scooter). When I try connect to ble device via bluetoothctl service it connects properly but disconnects after 2 minutes. I'm pretty sure that is something wrong with a pi zero bluetooth configuration or module?, because when I create connection between my laptop (Ubuntu 18) to BLE device there isn't any problem with it. I have tried change connections max and min intervals parameters, disable wifi (I heard about some interferencing) with no results.

Thanks on advance

Comment: Well, your Rpi + BLE problem is not strange, but "very common".  If your Ubuntu + Rpi config works, that means Rpi BlueZ5 might still be "slightly" buggy. Last buster release (sept 26) says the BT thing has been improved, so there still some hope, I mean, one or two releases later. PS, I have been troubled by the same problem for a couple of raspbian generations, from jessie or wheezy I forgot, ...;

Comment: Hmm, so there is nothing more than hope and waiting for fix bugs.

Comment: Well, If I got nothing to do some time, I might try again. Actually I have tried about 6 or 7 devices, one of them can pair and connect without any problem. I guess that one is a strong guy, with strong mouth and ears, therefore never lose touch.  Or I should try using USB BlueTooth dongle instead of the Rpi's very weak built in BlueTooth circuit and antenna.